# Positioning an image a certain distance away from the side in android

Tags: android, image, distance

Does anyone know how to position two a android image at a certain point away from the side in android. I have three images. One of them is in the center. The other two are meant to be located exactly the same distance either side of the image. The problem is that on the smaller screen sizes the two images appear at slightly different distances away from the central image. I believe this could be down to the natural scale of the android layout. It is difficult to move an image a small distance to fix the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 imageView side by side with a layout_weight="1" and a width of "0dp" in a LinearLayout to make them the same width

Use the padding/marging you want and they will fit.